# Basic stream/sed? bash script, perform substring on each line

Tags: bash, sed

I know this is basic, but I couldn't find the simplest way to iterate through a file with hundreds of lines and extract a substring.

If I have a file:

```
ABCY uuuu
UNUY uuuu

...
```

I want to end up with:

```
uuuu
uuuu
....
```

Ideally do a substring

{5} detect at character 5 and output that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need no `sed`:

```
cut -c5-9 yourfile
```

Comment: Thanks, cut works.   I have another side question.  How do you split a string.  I want to split based on a 'tab' character.

Comment: `cut -d<delimiter> -f<field(s)>` — actually, do the `man cut`, you never know what question to ask before you know your limitations and possibilities.

Comment: And yes, tab is the default delimiter for `cut`

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to use `cut` or `awk`. Assuming that your fields are separated by a space and you want the second field, you can use:

```
cut -d' ' -f2 file.txt

awk '{print $2}' file.txt
```

You can also use `cut` and `awk` to extract substrings:

```
cut -c6- file.txt
awk '{print substr($0,6);}'  file.txt
```

However, if you really want to iterate through the file and extract substrings, you can use a while loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo ${line:5}
done < file.txt
```

Comment: They aren't, I need the index.  I was just giving a hypothetical line.  Michael got it but your answer is also useful.

Answer (score 0):

if you really love sed, you could try:

```
sed -r 's/^.{5}//' file
```